# A caching solution for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, caching, webrequest

What I'm building is simply an application that fetches data over the web and displays them on the iOS views. Data are text and, sometimes, images / music files / movies.

I'd like to use some caching solution for the media. What it needs to do is:

- get an url of the file
- check if it's alredy downloaded in the cache storage, if it is, serve it
- if not, download it
- while also checking how much of the storage the current cache uses, and, if it's over the quota, delete oldest files

Best would be to have a simple interface for this - so I can just give an url and get the file of it (while files can change over time and reside on the same URL, so this should be handled too, in a perfect case).

Anyone knows a library to do it, on iPhone/iPad application?

Answer (score 2):

[ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) has a DownloadCache option that may work for you.  From their documentation:

> ```
> * You want to have access to the data when there is no internet connection and you can't download it again
> * You want to download something only if it has changed since you last downloaded it
> * The content you are working with will never change, so you only want to download it once
> ```

This is what I used in my iPad app and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at using a UIWebview for the view.  If I am understanding this correctly, you will be hosting your content on a web server and would simply like the iOS device to pull the content from the URL.  This is what UIWebview is.  It is essentially programmable access to Safari.

Comment: Well, I'll get the data as json/xml response, put them on views. While, for example, gallery, is produced by a list of URLs in a json, downloaded priorly, so it's not really a webview job...